# derivative of inverse of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials

Suppose $f(x)= 17x^{12}-124x^9+16x^3-129x^2+x-1$ determine $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1})$ at $x=-1$ if it exists.

**My Solution**

Inverse function is reflection of $f(x)$ about $y=x$ so behaviour of $f^{-1}(-1)$ around $x=-1$ is reflection of $f(x)$ around $x=f^{-1}(-1)$.

If at $(-1, f^{-1}(-1))$ derivative is $m_1=\tan \phi$ and at

$x=f^{-1}(-1)$, $f'(f^{-1}(-1))=m_2=\tan\psi$ then

$$\phi+\psi=\pi/2$$

Now say $f^{-1}(-1)=a$ then $f(a)=-1$ gives $a=0$(only solution i can find).

Hence $f'(a)=f'(0)=1$ this gives $\psi=\pi/4$, hence $\phi=\pi/4$ and hence $$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(-1))=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$g(f(x))=x \implies g’(f(x))f’(x)=1$, where $g = f^{-1}$.  Noting $f(0)=-1$, we then get $g’(-1)f’(0)=1 \implies g’(-1) = 1$

Comment: much simpler thank you.